# Declaring a struct in a .h file, defining it in a .c file and using the definition in another .c file?

Tags: c, abstract-class, abstract-data-type

I have the following:

***abstract.h***

```
typedef struct s_strukt strukt;
```

***abstract.c***

```
typedef struct s_strukt {
    int x;
} strukt;
```

***use_abstract.c***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "abstract.h"

int main() {

    strukt s;
    s.x = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

compiling, (gcc use_abstract.c) or (gcc use_abstract abstract.c) *use_abstract.c* results in the following error:

```
gcc use_abstract.c 
use_abstract.c:6:12: error: variable has incomplete type 'strukt' (aka 'struct s_strukt')
    strukt s;
           ^
./abstract.h:1:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct s_strukt'
typedef struct s_strukt strukt;
               ^
1 error generated.
```

how do I use the definition of *strukt* inside use_abstract.c?

Edit:
I do not want to define the struct inside the header file because I want to create different definitions for different .c files.

Edit2 (since people are reading wayyyyy to much into the "point" of the question instead of being intellectually stimulated):

**GOAL**

(1) Declare a struct in a header file (this case abstract.h)

(2) Define struct properties in a .c file (this case abstract.c)

(3) Use the definition from above in a new .c file (this case use_abstract.c accessing the defined struct in abstract.c, declared in abstract.h)

Comment: You define the `struct` in the header file `abstract.h` instead of in just one C file.

Comment: You can use pointers to a strukt. However you cannot allocate such pointers, nor de-reference them. You can however store them in memory and pass them to other functions.

Comment: @dmuir what do you mean, can you give an example? Preferably based on my minimally reproducible example.

Comment: Having a `typedef` like this in a abstract.c is pointless. The typedef won't be "seen" outside the abstract.c file.

Comment: @pointersarehard in a comment below you wrote _"I am going to create the struct differently in differnet .c files"_: you need to tell us more about this; [Edit] the question. Also read this: [The XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Jabberwocky This is a dummy example to understand the issue I am having at the moment. Look at my comments further below on an answer where I explain that I am trying to understand how to declare a struct in a header file, define it in a .c file and then use that definition in another c file. This is the issue I am having with my big code base. This is a minimally reproducible example and I tried to explain some usefullness to my implementation or rather my thoughts. Feel free to discard those if you are not interested or if you only want to answer the question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @pointersarehard the whole thing doesn't make much sense, see also Lundin's comments below. You need to tell us what you're _actually_  trying to achieve int the question and not spread around in comments.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I just did. I also did it in my edit and I also did it in comments further down. Please remove this comment, re-read what I've written and contemplate it. If you then have any further questions then please ask. However stop with the broad unhelpful comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare your ("public") structs in your headers and include those headers in the source where you're using it. Here your `use_abstract.c` only knows that there is a struct called `s_strukt` that exists by including `"abstract.h"`, but it doesn't know any of its fields.

And one more thing, use either one of these typedef in your header (both are the same) not both at the same time.

```c
// 1)
struct name { ... };
typedef struct name name; // rename "struct name" to "name"

// 2)
typedef struct { ... } name; // define name as the provided struct
```

Comment: I do not want to define the struct inside the header file because differnet .c files will have different definitions of the struct. Therefore alternative 2 goes away. When I use alternative 1 I get `use_abstract.c:6:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'strukt'; did you mean 'struct'?
    strukt s;` Or rather a twist of 1) in that I say there is a struct in .h and typedef define it in .c instead of typedef in each.

Comment: @pointersarehard "differnet .c files will have different definitions of the struct" Ok that doesn't make any sense at all. You are using the wrong solution, the next question is what problem you are actually trying to solve with it. Polymorphism?

Comment: technically you can define 2 different definitions in different translation units, or if you need some interface (like in java) or some abstraction you need to emulate them using a base struct, but I'm not sure what you need

Comment: @Lundin for example: two .c files will utilize "player" in two completely different ways. One will utilize player position, exclusively and another uses only the player items and hp exclusively. The main.c program uses all of these attributes of the player and maybe more. I do not want to allocate memory for player when I won't even use half of the memory I allocate. That is one, half good half bad, example of area of application.

Comment: @Lundin However I am not doing this in my code example, I am merely trying to figure this out, how to declare something in a .h file, define it in a .c file and use the definition in another .c file

Comment: @pointersarehard Then obviously you should make one struct containing (pointers to) two other structs, allocate each as needed. Then pass along the relevant inner structs to the different routines.

Comment: @Lundin. Simplified: I am trying to declare a struct in a .h, define it in a .c file, and access the definition in another .c file. That is it. That is what my reproducible example shows. Any further questions are welcome! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @pointersarehard If you want to use private encapsulation (no member access by caller), then you declare a struct in a h file and define it in a single C file. If you want to use the struct without private encapsulation (anyone can do member access), then you define the struct in a h file. Those are the only two valid use cases that make sense - pick one.